# Как сделать что бы после получения сигнала кнопка на qml начинает мигать красным?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

У меня есть интерфейс из трех кнопок, написанный на `QML`. На каждой кнопке есть цифровое значение, например, на кнопке `Давление` - значение давления воздуха.

Я хочу, чтобы когда приходило значение больше нормы, кнопка начинала мигать красным, и в идеале еще  появлялось окно с надписью "тревога".

Я даже не знаю как к этому подступиться, сейчас пробую вариант с `QPropertyAnimatiton`.

Answer (score 1):

Разделим логику работы с получением давления и проверкой его на превышение нормы от представления в `QML`. Создадим соответствующий класс:

AirPressure.h

```
#ifndef AIRPRESSURE_H
#define AIRPRESSURE_H

#include <QObject>

class AirPressure : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //объявляем члены, с которыми мы будем работать из qml
    //с соответствующими сеттерами, геттерами и сигналами изменения значений
    Q_PROPERTY(bool alert READ getAlert WRITE setAlert NOTIFY alertChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int airPressure READ getAirPressure WRITE setAirPressure NOTIFY airPressureChanged)
    int m_airPressure;
    bool m_alert;
public:
    explicit AirPressure(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void setAlert(bool alert);
    bool getAlert() const;
    void setAirPressure(int airPressure);
    int getAirPressure() const;

signals:
    void alertChanged();
    void airPressureChanged();
};

#endif // AIRPRESSURE_H
```

AirPressure.cpp

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include "AirPressure.h"

AirPressure::
AirPressure(QObject *parent):
    QObject{parent},
    m_airPressure{-1},
    m_alert{false}
{

    //dummy air pressure changes
    QTimer* t { new QTimer{this} };
    connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [this, gen = QRandomGenerator::system()]
    {
        setAirPressure(gen->generate() % 1000);
    });
    t->start(5000);
}

void
AirPressure::
setAlert(bool alert)
{
    m_alert = alert;
}

bool
AirPressure::
getAlert() const
{
    return m_alert;
}

void
AirPressure::
setAirPressure(int airPressure)
{
    m_airPressure = airPressure;
    setAlert(m_airPressure > 500);
    emit airPressureChanged();
    emit alertChanged();
}

int
AirPressure::
getAirPressure() const
{
    return m_airPressure;
}
```

Как видно в `setAirPressure`, если значение давления выше 500, что активируется тревога. Обязательно нужно послать сигналы об изменении значений, чтобы графический интерфейс об этом узнал.

При создании qml-контекста необходимо создать объект `AirPressure` и передать его туда.

```
AirPressure ap;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("airPressureGenerator", &ap);
```

Ну а дальше рисуем кнопку и обрабатываем полученные значения от `airPressureGenerator`

```
Item {
    id: button
    width: 100
    height: 100
    x: 100
    y: 100

    property color colorOk: "green"
    property color colorAlert: "red"

    RectangularGlow {
        id: effect
        anchors.fill: rect
        glowRadius: 5
        spread: 0.4
        color: airPressureGenerator.alert ? button.colorAlert : button.colorOk
        cornerRadius: rect.radius + glowRadius
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: anim
            running: airPressureGenerator.alert
            loops: Animation.Infinite;
            NumberAnimation  {
                target: effect
                property: "glowRadius"
                from: 5;
                to: 30;
                duration: 300
            }
            NumberAnimation  {
                target: effect
                property: "glowRadius"
                from: 30;
                to: 5;
                duration: 300
            }
       }
   }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: airPressureGenerator.alert ? button.colorAlert : button.colorOk
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100
        radius: 100
    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 75
        height: 75
        radius: 75
        Text {
            id: msg
            font.pixelSize: 15
            font.weight: Font.DemiBold
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 25
            text: qsTr("Давление")
            color: airPressureGenerator.alert ? button.colorAlert : button.colorOk
        }

        Text {
            id: pressure
            font.pixelSize: 15
            font.weight: Font.DemiBold
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 43
            text: airPressureGenerator.airPressure
            color: airPressureGenerator.alert ? button.colorAlert : button.colorOk
        }
    }
}
}
```